# Error when running a script (with a while Loop) in a script created background process

Tags: bash

Is it possible to use a while loop in a background job created by a script? This works perfectly fine when I manually run this in command prompt.

Called Script Content (test.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
> switch
echo 'Running' >> switch
check=$(more switch)
echo $check 

while [ $check = 'Running' ]
do
sleep 5s    
check=$(more switch)
    echo $check  
done
```

Calling Script Content (start.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
$PWD/test.sh &
```

I am getting an error:

> -bash: [: too many arguments

when the calling script runs. The called script run manually without issue. Is while loop not allow in a script created background job?

Comment: Put a '#' in front of '! /bin/bash'

Comment: Shouldn't that be a hashbang `#!` on the first line?

Comment: Your /path/to/script.sh probably has some syntax problem. Mind posting it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a minor syntax error.

Comment: The # is missing because it is a typo. The script path (/tmp/test.sh) is correct and there is no syntax error because it ran without issue without the &. Also, the script that I want to run in the background monitors a specific string in text file every n minutes.

Comment: The error is about the arguments to a `[` command, but there is no `[` command in the code you've posted. My guess is it's in /tmp/test.sh; just because it ran correctly without the & doesn't mean there's it's not the problem.

Comment: @user2799217: Is the missing `#` a typo in your script or in your question? If there's a typo in your question, please fix it. Copy-and-paste the exact contents of your script into your question. You haven't given us enough information to determine what the problem is.

Comment: @Keith, Thank you for your advice. I have updated the question with correct information.

Comment: @Gordon, I have simplified code to make it easier to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> echo 'Running' >> swtich
> check=$(more switch)
> ```

You write to a file called `swtich` and then read to a file called `switch`. That file doesn't exist, so the variable `check` ends up empty.

Incidentally, why call `more`? That's only useful to view a file page by page. If you're piping the output, `cat` is equivalent. If `more` doesn't have a controlling terminal, which happens when you call `test.sh` in the background, `more` prints an extra line containing the file name, so its output

So you really must use `cat` and not `more`. (In bash, you can also write `check=$(<switch)`.)

> ```
> [ $check = 'Running' ]
> ```

Since `$check` is empty, the command `[` receives three arguments: `=`, `Running` and `]`. This is not valid syntax for the `[` command.

**Always put double quotes around variable substitution and command substitution: `"$check"`, `"$(somecommand)"`.** If a `$` substitution occurs outside quotes, the result is split into separate words (0 words in your case, since the result was empty) and the words are interpreted as file glob patterns. This is almost never desirable, so always use double quotes unless you really have a list of glob patterns.

`check=$(cat switch)` is actually safe, because in an assignment, a single word is expected on the right-hand side, so word splitting doesn't happen. However, you might as well write `check="$(cat switch)"` for clarity. Also, the quotes are required if you write `export check="$(cat switch)"`.

So we have:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Running' >> switch
check=$(cat switch)

while [ "$check" = 'Running' ]
do
  sleep 5s
  check=$(cat switch)
done
```

In bash (but not in sh), you can write `[[ $check = Running ]]` instead of `[ $check = Running ]`. That's because `[[ … ]]` is special syntax, unlike `[` which is a built-in command with no special parsing. However, you would need double quotes if the variable was on the right-hand side of the `=` operator, because the right-hand side of `=` inside `[[ … ]]` is a pattern. Rather than learn such complicated rules, just use double quotes all the time and you'll be fine.

Comment: @user000001 Not if you want to run the script in older versions of bash, or in sh. I prefer to stick to portable constructs when there is no benefit.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, the double quote resolved the error. Did the start.sh work for you? The while loop is still not working for me when the background job was created from a script

Comment: @Londoner What do you mean by “not working”? If the issue is that `$check` doesn't seem to be equal to `Running`, see my edit: you really need to use `cat` and not `more`.

Comment: @KeithThompson But not the error message that was caused by it, so I'll keep my answer as is.

Comment: @Gilles: You might want to update your answer to reflect the edited question, to avoid confusion for future readers (who likely won't bother reading these comments).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
nohup yourprogram >>/dev/null 2>>/dev/null &
```

Your program content should not have & or nohup

Answer (score 0):

The problem is basically that you haven't quoted the argument in the test command. It should be

```
while [ "$check" = 'Running' ]
```

with double quotes around the variable. If you do that, you will notice that you have a typo in the first line. Instead of

```
echo 'Running' >> swtich
```

it should be

```
echo 'Running' >> switch
```

Then it should work as expected

As a side note, it is better not to use the more command to read the contents of the file, since it is intended for humans, but instead to just do:

```
check=$(<switch)
```

Comment: Thanks! The double quote got rid of the error. Did the start.sh work for you ?

Comment: @Londoner Yes it worked (after you remove the `switch` file). Of course the prompt returns immediately, since you run the script in the  background. But as soon as someone changes the contents of `switch`, the background process termites (You can see it with `ps`)